# microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered error fixing from code behind

Tags: vb.net, oledb

My application is working fine in 32 bit machine but when i rum my application from 64bit machine it is showing error like "microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0  provider is not registered". i searched for the solution and every one suggesting about installing 64 bit compatible OLEDB driver .I would like to know whether it is  fixed from code behind.Any valuuble suggestion are appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Subin

Comment: Witch version of Visual Studio are you using? Once you answer this question I will give you the answer according to your version

Comment: Paste your title into Google: [microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered error](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0%20provider%20is%20not%20registered) Take the first hit: [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

Comment: It is important that you select a good answer by clicking on the green check mark if no answer is good post an update so we help you. If you found the answer yourself post it in answers and mark it as good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer might look strange but have you seen this solution  ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzLA_z7tDPs)?

I mean especially first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the target CPU to work on 64bit  and 32bit

1. Go to the startup project of your program.
2. Open the properties window.
3. Click the compile tab.
4. Click advanced compile options.
5. Change the target CPU options to any CPU.